# Can we use same id for different blocks in a page if one block at a time is hidden

Tags: html

I have two tabs content with same id. Can i use it like this.

```html
<div>
  <div class="tab1" style="display:none">
    <div id="abc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2">
    <div id="abc"></div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: It´s not valid but it´s definetly working. Just remember if you try directly calling it e.g in js (jquery) '$("#abc)' it will select both so you have to differ with the parent e.g. $(.tab1 #abc). You should avoid it cause of that. And if you use it anyway multiple times why not just use also an class there ?

Comment: I came across this situation and just want to know if its valid.

Comment: Thanks @Doomenik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id:

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which **must be unique in the whole document**. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

Of course, browsers will still render it correctly and apply styles correctly and you won't notice anything weird, unless you start using functions like `getElementById` which are designed to return only one element. Depending on the browser they'll probably always return the first element, regardless if such element is visible or not.

I worked with few templates where multiple elements ended up having the same ID, and you can definitely work around it, but functions like `getElementById` are sort of useless in those scenarios.

Comment: every browser will probably return the first occurrence, it just depends if you do a breadth first or depth first search. Maybe every known implementation out there is performing depth first search since it's less memory intensive. (I've updated it to make it less confusing)

Comment: So it is not advisable to use it like this. Thanks for the reply @peter